Bitcoin to usd$$$$$$
I bought a few programs and set them up. I was incapacitated for 12 mos. Recently I had finance tell me I have 1.3 btc that needs to be converted. Is it true you have to pay finance 75 to convert it. They also said my info was breached. What should I do.i don't wanna be scammed
